# Intel C Compiler unable to use standard libs (e.g. dirent.h) on Linux

Tags: c, linux, icc

I am having an issue with the Intel C Compiler `icc`, which refuses to recognize some standard libraries such as dirent.h. My code looks like this:

```
#include <dirent.h>
...
DIR* dir = opendir(path);
...
readdir(dir);
dirent* entry = readdir(dir);
while(entry != NULL) {
    ...
    entry = readdir(dir);
}
```

Upon trying to compile the code, I get the following error, even if I explicitly add `-I/usr/include` to the command:

```
icc -g -ipp=common -mkl=parallel -I/opt/intel/ipp/include -I"../include" -std=c99 -openmp -cilk-serialize -fpic -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -c -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.c"
../src/main.c(85): error: identifier "dirent" is undefined
dirent* entry = readdir(dir);
```

GCC compiles the same code withough any problem - unfortunately, I need to compile my application with ICC for other reasons.

I appreciate you advice :)

Comment: I tested the same on Linux Mint 14, which is based on Ubuntu Quantal/12.10 and on SuSE SLES 11 with icc version 13.1.1. GCC versions are 4.3.4 and 4.7.2.

Comment: did you try "struct dirent" instead of dirent?

Comment: yes, of course. The problem is just that the compiler stops at the first error. If I'm not assigning the result of readdir, the compiler returns the same error message for readdir. I tried all sorts of things and searched for answers for several hours. Also, as mentioned before the same code works flawlessly whith GCC, so it's not a syntactic issue - downvoting seems a little harsh though...

Comment: What if you replace the relative path in `-I"../include"` with the absolute path ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, by the way if you put struct there you probably avoid stupid questions like mine :D

Comment: @Jekyll: Yeah, sorry of course the struct should go there and I didn't want to blame you for downvoting - that comment was meant for whomever did that :D

Comment: @Alex I think he is including the correct path as the error is in line 85... otherways he would get an error immediatly

Comment: @Alex: as Jekyll stated, I tried that but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: @MaxPlauth can you check manually the content of dirent.h in your toolchain?

Comment: Did you try it with a SSCCE like  `#include <dirent.h> int main(void) {struct dirent * pde = readdir(""); return 0}`?

Comment: @alk yes I tried that - didn't help either :(

Comment: Ok, I'm using NSight Eclipse edition with the Intel compiler integration tools and it seems that this exotic combination resulted in weird flags, which messed up the preprocessor statments in dirent.h. Manually entering the icc line from terminal for the SSCCE pointed me to that. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

In C language, you must declare variables at the start of a C block {}. You cannot have declarations interleaved between instructions.

Comment: This is no longer necessary.  You are using a very old compiler.